# Can i copy the data from one div to another div using JavaScript .value property?

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I am very new to JS here what i want to do is just copy the data from one div to another div by using JS but i am getting undefined error

```
<div id="div_one">Hello</div>
<div id="div_two"></div>

<script>
document.getElementById("div_two").innerHTML = 
document.getElementById("div_one").value;
</script>
```

Comment: you can use `.value` to input elements to make it work try `document.getElementById("div_two").innerHTML = 
document.getElementById("div_one").innerHTML;`

Comment: so, we can use `.value` to input elements only or nowhere else ?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You need to take [`innerHTML`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML) property for getting the value.

`value` is only available for [some elements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Attributes), like `<button>`, `<option>`, `<input>`, `<li>`, `<meter>`, `<progress>`, `<param>`.

```js
document.getElementById("div_two").innerHTML =
    document.getElementById("div_one").innerHTML;
```

```html
<div id="div_one">Hello</div>
<div id="div_two"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks, its working now

Answer (score 6):

According to [`innerHTML` MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML):

> **Note**: If a `<div>`, `<span>`, or `<noembed>` node has a child text node that includes the characters (&), (<), or (>), `innerHTML` returns these characters as `&amp`, `&lt` and `&gt` respectively. Use [`Node.textContent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/textContent) to get a correct copy of these text nodes' contents.
>
> - `textContent` often has better performance because the text is not parsed as HTML.
> - Moreover, using `textContent` can prevent XSS attacks.

In this sense you may also try alternative properties:

```js
let div1IH = document.getElementById("div_one").innerHTML;
console.log(div1IH);
let div1TC = document.getElementById("div_one").textContent;
console.log(div1TC);
let div1IT = document.getElementById("div_one").innerText;
console.log(div1IT);
document.getElementById("div_two").innerHTML = div1IH;
document.getElementById("div_three").innerHTML = div1TC;
document.getElementById("div_four").innerHTML = div1IT;
```

```html
<div id="div_one">Hello & > _ < & </div>
<div id="div_two"></div>
<div id="div_three"></div>
<div id="div_four"></div>
```

Since in this case you might want to copy the HTML content, the `innerHTML` may be adequate, but if you are going to use that data as text only, you might prefer the alternative properties above.